# Error in as.environment(x) : invalid object for 'as.environment' in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a new user of R, i have tried the following code. It gives an error. Can anyone help, please. The codes are:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
qplot(price, data=diamonds)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Yesterday I updated my R to 3.0.0 but had problems with emacs, so I rolled back to 2.15.3. But now `ggplot2` doesn't work. I've even rolled `ggplot2` back to the second-last version, but the error still happens. Also with this alternative MWE:
`ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()` 
Is it a `ggplot2` issue? As I said, I rolled `ggplot2` back but not its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I am running R (2.15.3) in a x64 Wintel computer, having the very same problem.

I just googled around and found the following solution:

1st - From a fresh R session (not using RStudio, just in case), uninstall the packages "ggplot2", "scales", "plyr", "reshape2", "gtable"

```
remove.packages(c("ggplot2","scales","plyr","reshape2","gtable"))
```

2nd - quit R and go to your library directory. I had found that plyr library is not completely removed by remove.packages, keeping the plyr ddl in the system. Then manually remove the library folders, if needed.

3rd - Start R again and install again the libraries.

```
install.packages(c("ggplot2", "scales", "plyr", "reshape2", "gtable"))
```

4th - Update packages to get the latest versions.

```
update.packages(ask=FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE)
```

5th - I runned a very symple example to check that ggplot2 is properly installed:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
ggplot(mtc, aes(x = factor(gear))) + geom_bar(stat = "bin")
```

A very simple barplot should be rendered.

Hope it works for you!

D.